# Mybatis Batch insert Java BigDecimal to SQL Server decimal(18,2) not working correctly

Tags: java, sql-server, decimal, mybatis

Seeing that every suggestion us using `BigDecimal` to avoid the precision problem.

I'm using `BigDecimal` in java with the SQL Server column `Decimal(18,2)`.

When I insert value with `new BigDecimal("37.99")` it turns out that the value in the database is 38.

I also tried using `new BigDecimal(str).setScale(2, RoundingMode.UNNECESSARY)` and still, get 38 in the database.

How should I avoid this problem?

Comment: FYI your question's title says `decimal(18,4)` but your question's body says `Decimal(18,2)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found the solution

I'm using myBatis batch insert to insert the value,

and some of the value is 0 and I didn't set the scale in the program

turn out the batch using the least scale to insert all record

after I set every BigDecimal value with

```
new BigDecimal("37.99").setScale(2)
```

the database value went correct.

Hope anyone could get help with this answer.